# Firefox CSS Float and NoWrap Bug

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have a few `<td>` elements within a `<table>` where I want all elements on the same line with no wrapping. I am using css `white-space: nowrap;` By default, all elements are horizontally aligned to the left and so I also use some `float:right;` to space some elements.

This works great in Chrome, but in Firefox it seems to add another line and its a weird bug. How can I keep everything on the same line in FIREFOX?

scenario 1

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">

    <a data-id="10796" data-pr="MOV1">AGG55TTYY</a>

    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#0fb124; font-weight:bold; float:right; vertical-align:middle;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span style="color:#eeeeee;"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
        <span style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000;">2</span>
    </span>

</td>
```

scenario 2 and 3

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">

   MOV3<span style="font-size:11px; color:#AAAAFF; font-weight:bold; float:right; vertical-align:middle;">#JJ655</span>

</td>
```

Comment: tables are for tabular data, if you are floating things right and left in a cell, it doesn't seem tabular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your issue by either adding float left to the anchor:

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

    <a data-id="10796" data-pr="MOV1" style="float:left">AGG55TTYY</a>

    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#0fb124; font-weight:bold; float:right; vertical-align:middle;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span style="color:#eeeeee;"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000;">2</span>
    </span>

  </td>
</table>
```

Or putting your anchor after your span

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#0fb124; font-weight:bold; float:right; vertical-align:middle;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span style="color:#eeeeee;"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000;">2</span>
    </span>

    <a data-id="10796" data-pr="MOV1">AGG55TTYY</a>

  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Works great - Thx